# Java Socket, small string needlessly being split across two packets

Tags: java, sockets

I was attempting to communicate to a device server with Sockets, after having my little Java program hang when on `readLine` I ended up having to inject my target application with a packet sniffer and found out that `os.writeBytes("notify\n");` was being split to two packets, the first containing `n` and the next `otify`, of which the server did not like. I fixed this by adding another `writeBytes` before hand:

`os.writeBytes(" ");

os.writeBytes("notify\n");

os.flush();`

This to me seems a bit hacky and potentially unstable, could someone shed some light why I'm having to do this and give me a better solution.

Cheers

Comment: TCP sockets, or something else?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using writeBytes instead of a different flavor of write?

Comment: If you're sending the string over a TCP connection I can't think of a reason why this would cause problems since TCP provides a data communications stream. Try flushing the output stream (os.flush()) after writing the string.

Answer (score 2):

When working with raw socket connections, you can never assume that you will get your messages in discrete chunks.  In a production environment, its entirely possible you will receive partial messages, or multiple messages at a time.

If you don't want to deal with this, you should consider using a library like [Netty](https://www.jboss.org/netty/) which handles these concerns for the programmer.

Having said that, I agree with Thomas that your problem is probably related to your choice of `writeBytes`.